# I'm not a play by the rules kind of guy vs I'm not the play by the rules kind of guy?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-structure

**I'm not a play by the rules kind of guy**

or

**I'm not the play by the rules kind of guy**

Which one is right? And should I use hypens between every word for *play by the rules*?

Answer (score 2):

**I'm not *a* play-by-the-rules kind of guy.**

**play-by-the-rules** is a [compound adjective](https://www.grammar.com/compound-adjectives/). It's hyphenated to make it clear that it's acting as a single word/adjective or idea.

However, it's worth mentioning that if it comes **after** the noun instead of before, the answer is different:

**I'm not *the* kind of guy who *plays by the rules***.

In your example, even without the hyphens, there's little doubt about how to interpret the meaning of the sentence. So when the phrase is used after the noun, it's not unusual to drop the hyphens.

Sometimes, however, it's not clear how to interpret the sentence if you omit the hyphens. In these cases, hyphens are typically used whether the modifier comes before or after the noun. For example:

> I'm taking an algebra intensive course. (an algebra course that's intensive)

versus

> I'm taking an algebra-intensive course. (a course that's algebra-intensive)

**Exception**: When the first word in the compound adjective ends in **ly**, you do not use hyphens. For example:

> publicly traded  (**not** publicly-traded)

> recently acquired (**not** recently-acquired)

The rules are confusing and aren't always applied consistently, so you might just need to consult a dictionary if you're not sure.

Answer (score 0):

swcmcdonnell explained the compound adjective pretty well, so I will try and answer the article question.

"*A* thing" means "one of many possible things".
"*The* thing" means one specific thing.

For example, "I saw a lion at the zoo" - there are many possible lions I could have seen.  "I saw the lion at the zoo" - there is only one lion at the zoo that I could have seen.

There can be more than one "play-by-the-rules kind of guy", so *a* is more appropriate.  "*The* play-by-the-rules kind of guy" implies that there is only one "play-by-the-rules kind of guy".  There might be more than one in the world, but not in this situation.